# Alternative to mencoder and ffmpeg for timelapse in Raspbian Jessie

Tags: video

`mencoder` and `ffmpeg` are no longer included in the Raspbian repositories since Jessie was released. `mencoder` was previously used in an RPi Foundation tutorial [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/timelapse-setup/worksheet/) to compile a timelapse video.

I've seen that `avconv` can be used to do the same thing, and it **is** included in Raspbian Jessie, but what command should I use for that?

My folder of stills looks like this:

```
photo1.jpg  photo2.jpg  photo3.jpg  photo4.jpg  photo5.jpg
photo6.jpg  photo7.jpg  photo8.jpg  photo9.jpg   photo10.jpg
...
```

The previous command looked like this:

```
ls *.jpg > stills.txt; mencoder -nosound -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:aspect=16/9:vbitrate=8000000 -vf scale=1920:1080 -o timelapse.avi -mf type=jpeg:fps=24 mf://@stills.txt
```

How could I do this with `avconv` or another command that is supported in Raspbian Jessie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a reasonably simple approach given at [techedemic.com](http://techedemic.com/2014/09/18/creating-a-timelapse-clip-with-avconv/):

Name all image files sequentially.

avconv can (apparently - I haven't checked) require names with a leading string followed by 0000/0001/0002/etc. Convert your file names using:

```
ls *.JPG| awk 'BEGIN{ a=0 }{ printf "mv %s myfile%04d.JPG\n", $0, a++ }' | bash
```

With everything renamed, use the following command to create a clip with the original resolution, and at high quality:

```
avconv -y -r 10 -i myfile%4d.JPG -r 10 -vcodec libx264 -q:v 3  -vf crop=4256:2832,scale=iw:ih tlfullhiqual.mp4;
```

Explanation:

> -y forces avconv to overwrite any file
>
> -r 10 creates a clip with 10 frames per seconds (for some versions of avconv you have to specify it twice)
>
> -i specifies the input file(s). %4d means any 4 decimal numbers
>
> -vcodec specifies the video codec to be used (H.264 in this case)
>
> -q:v specifies the quality, value ranges from 1 (best) to 31 (worse)
>
> crop= specifies which area of the images will be cropped
>
> scale= indicates how much scaling must take place (in the above example iw:ih
>   indicates that the output width and height will be that of the in
>   width and in height)
>
> the last parameter is the output file

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for viewing stills as a movie is to use [VidMyFigs.com](http://vidmyfigs.com), which allows you to view the resulting "movie" in any javascript-enabled Web browser.